# Launch Android activity from non-activity class

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm using a third-party application that just launches a class that extends another normal class. 
So, from that class I would like to launch an activity:

```
public class SkyTest extends VtiUserExit {


    @Override
    public VtiUserExitResult execute() throws VtiExitException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logInfo("TEST");

    return null;
    }

}
```

How do I launch an activity named `MainActivity` from here?

I tried this:

```
Context context = null;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

but it's not working. I know I can't use the null context, but how do I create a context so it works?

Answer (score 2):

A `null` context doesn't work because Android needs that Application Context in order to find your Activity. I don't know which framework you are using, but you should look for a way to grab a reference to the Context, have you gone through the API for the class you're extending?

Comment: I'm using SkyTechnologies framework, I'm loading data from SAP, with it, and i need to print a ticket. On sky i just can launch an .apk with a class extended from VtiUserExit. All the API from sky is just used to import and export data from the DBs. Is there a way to grab a reference of the context of the principal SkyMobile app?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with that framework. It doesn't look like the API reference is publicly available either.